# The use of article "the"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I sometimes get confused about how to use the article "the". 
For example, let's look at the following sentences.

1. In comparison with **the** hand-picked method and above mentioned instrumental measurement, optical non-destructive measurement techniques are attempted to examine external **or** internal quality of blueberry.
2. In comparison with **the** hand-picked method and **the** above mentioned instrumental measurement, optical non-destructive measurement techniques are attempted to examine external **or** internal quality of blueberry.

I am not sure if it is okay to use "the" only once. And I am also wondering if the conjunction "or" can be used here.

What's more, I was told that uncountable nouns don't need articles. I don't know whether I should add "the" before uncountable nouns.

For example,
1. Sample queue **showed the considerable potential**  for establishing a simple but robust classifier.

2. Sample queue **showed considerable potential**  for establishing a simple but robust classifier.

Are these sentences correct?

I would feel much obliged if you can kindly help me with these questions. I have  read the use of articles in the grammar book, but still can't get really clear about the use.

Comment: Sentence 2 is better than sentence 1. However you need a further definite article in front of "external" - "...to examine the external or internal quality of blueberry".

Comment: @WS2 Sentence 2? Which one?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth First one. With the second pair, both highlighted portions are idiomatic. But an article of some sort is needed at the start, before "sample queue".

Comment: Huijing Huang please be aware this not your problem alone; it is very important; it belongs to English Language Learners.

Many - perhaps half or more - even of European language speakers find English articles almost completely incomprehensible and my assumption is that your name indicates your main language is a lot less like English than any of theirs…